# Installing PostgreSQL on Centos 5

Tags: postgresql, centos5, public-key

I'm following the instructions from [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation). I try and run

`yum localinstall http://yum.postgresql.org/9.4/redhat/rhel-5-i386/pgdg-centos94-9.4-1.noarch.rpm`

which returns the fault `cannot open file... Skipping.`

I tried to `wget` the file and ran yum install `pgdg-centos94-9.4-1.noarch.rpm` which returns the error

`warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 442df0f8`

`Public key for pgdg-centos94-9.4-1.noarch.rpm is not installed`

Sorry, server admin isn't my strong suit and am struggling to figure out what to do.

Comment: `yum localinstall` doesn't make sense with a HTTP URL. You can't `localinstall` from a remote source. I think you mean `yum install`. As for the key warning - that's fine, it's just telling you it cannot verify the provenance of the package.

Comment: yeah, didn't make a lot of sense to me either but I swear thats what it says in the instructions.

Comment: Well, once you installed the rpm and did a `yum check-update` could you `yum install postgresql94` without problems? (BTW, CentOS/RHEL5 is ancient. You should *not* be installing anything new on it, you should be most of the way through planning to migrate off it.)

Comment: Once the warning comes up it doesn't look like it installs. When I tried to install it says no package postgresql94 available. It's an laptop I just have lying around. Didn't want to spend much time updating it.

Comment: Good luck then. I think you are wasting your time by *not* clean installing a current OS on it.